# Finding the angle of inclination of a cone.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

After my lecture on solving triple integrals with spherical coordinates, we defined $\phi$ as the angle of inclination from the positive z-axis such that $0\leq \phi \leq\pi$.

What I don't understand is given an equation of a cone:
$$z= c \, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ 
for some constant c, why is:

$$\phi = \arctan \left (\frac{1}{c} \right )$$

Our professor just did not justify this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x = 0$. Then, for any $y$, consider the line from $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,y,\pm cy)$. Do you see why the angle formed is $\arctan(1/c)$?. Note that this is all symmetric, so the fixed value of $x$ doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

$ z = c\, r $ is the generator of cone slanting side, apex at origin.

slope of cone generator = $$ \dfrac {dr}{dz} =\tan \phi =\dfrac{1}{c}. $$